# Argument dependent lookup for friend functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

Consider the following:

```
namespace N {
    struct A { };

    struct B {
        B() { }
        B(A const&) { }
        friend void f(B const& ) { }
    };
}

int main() {
    f(N::B{}); // ok
    f(N::A{}); // error
}
```

In the first case, the case succeeds - we consider the associated namespaces of `N::B` and find `N::f(B const&)`. Great.

The second case fails. Why? According to [[namespace.memdef]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3):

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. [...] If a friend function or function template
>   is called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the function arguments (3.4.2).

The associated namespace of `N::A` is `N`, of which `f` is a member, so why is it not found by lookup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `f` is not declared in an associated class. `B` is an associated class when the argument is of type `B`, but not when the argument is of type `A`.

I quote from [basic.lookup.argdep]/4, emphasis mine:

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as the lookup performed when the
>   associated namespace is used as a qualifier (3.4.3.2) except that:
>
> — Any using-directives in the associated namespace are ignored.
>
> — Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates **declared in associated classes** are
>   visible within their respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup (11.3).
>
> — All names except those of (possibly overloaded) functions and function templates are ignored.